# Mac OS X, C Facilities for reading PCI device information

Tags: c, macos, pci

I'm trying to learn how to get information from PCI devices in Mac OS X. So far I haven't been able to find anything about it in sysctl(3) and it seems the old devinfo(3) facilities from BSD are not available.

I need a C facility for this, I know there is an I/O kit framework for Objective C but I cannot use this.

The specific information I'm after is pretty basic, just vendor and device ID's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I/O Kit *is* the system framework for device information. It is not an Objective-C API; instead, Apple use a restricted subset of C++. Quoting the [I/O Kit Fundamentals](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Features/Features.html) document,

> Apple considered several programming languages for the I/O Kit and chose a restricted subset of C++.
>
> C++ was chosen for several reasons. The C++ compiler is mature and the language provides support for system programming. In addition, there is already a large community of Macintosh (and BSD) developers with C++ experience.
>
> The restricted subset disallows certain features of C++, including
>
> - Exceptions
> - Multiple inheritance
> - Templates
> - Runtime type information (RTTI)—the I/O Kit uses its own implementation of a runtime typing system
>
> These features were dropped because they were deemed unsuitable for use within a multithreaded kernel. If you feel you need these features, you should reconsider your design. You should be able to write any driver you require using I/O Kit with these restrictions in place.

If you cannot use C++ then one alternative is to have your C program call `/usr/bin/ioreg` and parse its results.

---

**Edit:** you might want to take a look at the [Accessing Hardware from Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_Finding_Devices/AH_Finding_Devices.html) document. It looks like accessing the I/O registry can be done with C code for the most part (if not all), with a bit of Core Foundation.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, very valuable information. I will wait and see, if no one else makes their voice heard then I will assume that there are no facilities for doing this that do not involve other languages than C.

Comment: @Hjemmedyrker Take a look at my last edit. It seems that browsing the I/O registry might not require C++ at all.